# Username Variable in custom links?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm trying to use custom links in the php code to link to buddypress profile pages.

Basically, I need a way to create a username constant so I can make links like

domain.com/members/--username--/profile
domain.com/members/--username--/settings
domain.com/members/--username--/other

with --username-- being the constant which changes the currently logged in user who clicks the link?

I Am sure this could be done in functions.php with a rewrite code but not sure where to begin.

If anyone could help it would be majorly appreciated... This has been racking my brain for weeks. I have no problems implementing the code... Just no idea how to create it?

Answer (score 1):

The User data of the currently logged in user in WordPress can be retrieved via `wpget_current_user()`

So you should be able to do something like this in your theme or wherever.

```
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<a href="http://example.com/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile">Your profile</a>.';
```

And build your link that way.

HTH

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it didn't work :(

Comment: some more information would be good. What exactly did you do? What did not work?

Comment: hey, so here's the current code,

`$actions = array(
   'edit-profile' => html( 'a', array( 'href' => appthemes_get_edit_profile_url() ), __( 'Edit Profile', APP_TD ) ),
   'logout' => html( 'a', array( 'href' => wp_logout_url() ), __( 'Logout', APP_TD ) ),
  );`

and i tried replacing it with 

`$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo "<a href="http://example.com/members/" . $current_user->user_login . '/profile">Your profile</a>`

but i get 500 internal server error. I'm trying to replace the edit profile link with a buddypress profile link.

Comment: where's this code from? We're completely missing the context here. What the code that I gave you does is just output a link. The Code above just fills $actions with an array. Replacing one with the other doesn't work. The code above doesn't render a link to the frontend but only define an array. That can't work.

Comment: Ahh i see. and it's from the appthemes ideas theme. Is there a way to perhaps remove the array and recode it to use the php code you supplied. saying that, when i tried your code outside of any function i get 500 internal server error.

Comment: oh yeah there's a typo in my code. I just corrected that in my original post. If you use this code now it should work - at least outside of any theme specialities.